# I need to get the value of the array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

My array structure is

```
Array
(

    [customer_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [customer_id] => 123
                )
        )
    [menu_item_net_price] => 1700
    [menu_item_tax_price] => 4%
    [menu_item_gross_price] => 1700
    [provider_id] => 123
)
```

I need to get the value of `[customer_id] => 123`. Tell me how can I do that?

Still my problem is not solved so I am posting code:

```
$data['customer_id'] = $this->session->userdata('id');
            $data['menu_item_net_price']= $netPrice;
            $data['menu_item_tax_price']= '4%'; 
            $data['menu_item_gross_price']= $netPrice;
            $data['provider_id']= 123; 
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($data);
            echo '</pre>';
            exit(0);
```

Comment: Are you sure that you asked the right question? Maybe you need to put `customer_id` into array?

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/arrays

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo $data['customer_id'][0]['customer_id'];
```

Comment: I think he's maybe looking for `$cid = $this->session->userdata('id'); $data['customer_id'] = $cid[0]['customer_id'];`, but +1 for sheer bloody-minded literalness :-D

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep format of the array, you could do it like:

```
<?php
$data['customer_id'] = $this->session->userdata('id');
$data['customer_id'] = $data['customer_id'][0]['customer_id'];
$data['menu_item_net_price']= $netPrice;
$data['menu_item_tax_price']= '4%';
$data['menu_item_gross_price']= $netPrice;
$data['provider_id']= 123;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the format of your array it's simple:

```
<?php
$data[$this->session->userdata('id')]['menu_item_net_price']= $netPrice;
$data[$this->session->userdata('id')]['menu_item_tax_price']= '4%';
$data[$this->session->userdata('id')]['menu_item_gross_price']= $netPrice;
$data[$this->session->userdata('id')]['provider_id']= 123;

echo $data[$customer_id]['provider_id']; //echoes 123
?>
```